every point in an open set of $R^n$ has an open neighborhood intersecting only finitely many cubes.
In the lecture on the manifold theory, my professor said "An open set $U \subset R^n$ can be written as a countable union of cubes such that every $p\in U$ has an open neighborhood intersecting only finitely many cubes."
I understand the first part of the statement "An open set $U \subset R^n$ can be written as a countable union of cubes" but could not understand the second part "every $p\in U$ has an open neighborhood intersecting only finitely many cubes."

It means that the cubes form a locally finite collection.  See the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_finite_collection .

Yes, but how can we find such a locally finite collection of cubes?

Divide $\Bbb R^n$ into a lattice of hypercubes of sidelength $1$. For your open set $U$, let $\mathcal C_0$ be the set of all such cubes lying entirely inside $U$. As there are only countably many cubes in the lattice, $\mathcal C_0$ must be countable.
Next, divide the remaining cubes not in $\mathcal C_0$ into $2^n$ cubes of sidelength $\frac 12$. Let $\mathcal C_1$ be the set of all the half-length hypercubes that lie entirely inside $U$. Etc.
Define $\mathcal C = \bigcup_k \mathcal C_k$. $\mathcal C$ is obviously countable. If $p \in U$,
there is some ball about $p$ inside $U$ of some radius $r$. Let $k$ be large enough that the longest diagonal length of a cube of sidelength $2^{-k}$ is less than $r$. Consider the lattice of the cubes of sidelength $2^{-k}$ in $\Bbb R^n$. Since the lattice covers $\Bbb R^n$, $p$ is contained in some of the those cubes - either in the interior or the shared boundaries. But no point is in more that $2^n$ of these cubes. Further, every cube that $p$ belongs to is entirely inside the ball, and thus entirely inside the open set. And the interior of the union of the cubes to which $p$ belongs is a neighbhorhood of $p$. All of these cubes are either in $\mathcal C_k$ or else they are subsets of cubes in various $\mathcal C_i$ for values $i < k$. So the union of the cubes is entirely contained inside $\bigcup \bigcup_{i \le k} \mathcal C_i$. And finally $p\notin \bigcup\bigcup_{i > k} \mathcal C_i$ as the cubes in all the $\mathcal C_i$ only intersect in their boundaries, thus no later cube can touch the now-surrounded $p$.
Thus $\mathcal C$ is a countable locally finite collection of cubes whose union is $U$.
